# Infinite vertical loop scrolling Windows Phone/Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I just started to learn WP development and coming from the Web development world, understanding XAML can be quite challenging. So this might be a very rookie questions, I hope somebody can give me at least some hints.

So using a `ListBox`, when the user reach the bottom, I want to display the initial items again at after the last results, so if the user keeps scrolling down, it gives the sensation of infinite loop (without the need to fetch new results). Of course I will also need to hide the scrollbar, but I will take care of that later.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use LoopingSelector from Silverlight toolkit for Windows Phone.
For more details check http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-loopingselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api and http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/using-loopingselector-from-the-silverlight-toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

You can create AttachedProperty for ListBox to fire event and to load new datas when the User scrolls to the end. If you are beginner it might be difficult. So you can use [**this**](http://danielvaughan.orpius.com/post/scroll-based-data-loading-in-windows-phone-7.aspx). I have used this in one of my WP projects. You can download his solution from the link.

After adding his classes to your project, you must register needed class in your xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
         u:ScrollViewerMonitor.AtEndCommand="{Binding FetchMoreDataCommand}" />
```

But he has used MVVM arhitecture, if you haven't used MVVM, you can learn it also from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/221585/Step-By-Step-Guide-To-MVVM).

Alse this might be very helpful if you want to understand what is **AttachedProperty** from [here](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2010/05/attached-dependency-properties-for.html).